# Elements won't display on the same row

Tags: html, css, row, display

I tried using display: inline-block; to get the elements on the same row but it keeps moving down. I tried using margin to adjust the position but that'll mess up the responsive web function. 
Here's how it looks now:
[image]

Here's how it should  look:
[image]

My code so far:

```css
#header .logo-wrap { padding: 50px 0 50px 0; }

#header p.site-desc {
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align-last: right;
width:70%;
  padding-top: -5px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
 }
 
#carousel {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width:70%;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-wrap">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="desktop-6 columns">
     <h1><a href="index.html" title="Home"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wobJUCd.png" alt="" /></a></h1>
    <!-- // .desktop-6 -->

    
     <p class="site-desc">
      Digital media designer<br />
      Concept developer<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <p style="font-size:75px; line-height:50px; text-align-last: justify; letter-spacing: 3px; color: #595959; font-family:  Neusa ExtraBold;">i</p></p>
      

    <div id="carousel">
  <div class="btn-bar">
    <div id="buttons"><a id="prev" href="#"></a><a id="next" href="#"></a> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slides">
    <ul>
      <li class="slide">
        <div class="quoteContainer">
          <p class="quote-phrase"
       
                    style="font-size:44px; line-height:45px; text-align-last: justify; letter-spacing: 3px; color: #595959; font-family:  Neusa ExtraBold;"> minimize,</br>experiment,</br>& make grids</span>
     </p>
      </div>
         </li>
    
    </ul>
  </div>
</div></div>
     <!-- // .site-desc -->
    </div><!-- // .desktop-6 -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div><!-- // .container -->
  </div><!-- // .logo-wrap -->
```

Answer (score 0):

use float left for each element or for the ul to make it inline use ul li { display:inline; }